# How does one strengthen their sense of rhythm?

Tags: style, rhythm

Many pieces of writing are succinct, but they are not rhythmical, giving no pleasure to the ear of the reader. The reason for that is likely this: The writers themselves either are unmindful of rhythm when they write, or possess a poor ability to formulate rhythm. So the question I want to ask is this: How does a writer strengthen their ear for rhythm?

Comment: I suggest planning the rhythm before you start writing. Outline the events and put them into an order that creates rhythm. Then write the story. Some writers can write amazing stuff without planning, and good on them. But a lot of writers start with careful planning.

Comment: @AndrewBrēza I assumed the question was about rhythm in terms of style, voice, prose etc, not about plotting, although I may be wrong

Comment: I wasn't entirely clear either, which is why I didn't provide an answer. Hopefully my comment was helpful but the answers here are much better.

Answer (score 3):

Paying attention to rhythm (i.e., caring about it) is the first step. After that, I recommend reading some instructional material on the subject. A book that has helped me greatly in many areas of writing (not just rhythm) is *On Writing Well* by William F. Zinsser. It is probably out of print, but if you can get hold of a copy, I highly recommend it.

One more suggestion: read what you have written aloud. Doing so will uncover many problems with rhythm and wording.

Comment: +1 for reading aloud

Answer (score 2):

Ray Bradbury recommended reading poetry.  Every day.

It does help.